# VueJs. Поиск статьи по окончанию ввода текста

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть input для ввода текста:

```
<input type="search" class="input_search"
    autocomplete="off"
    v-model.trim="query"
    placeholder="Поиск по названию"
    @keyup="sendSearch">
<!-- @change="sendSearch"> -->
```

Дата:

```
data() {
    return {
      query: '',
      res: [],
    }
  },
```

И метод:

```
async sendSearch() {
  console.log( this.query )
  // this.res = await postSearchByTitles(this.query)
  // setTimeout(() => console.log( this.query ), 1000)
},
```

И функция для связи с бэкендом

```
import { postSearchByTitles } from '~/services/api'
// Поиск постов по названиям (title - мультиязычное)
// export async function postSearchByTitles(title) {
//     return await get(`posts/search/${title}`)
// }
```

Сейчас функция поиска срабатывает либо при вводе каждого символа (@keyup) и отправляет кучу последовательных запросов к API (что нагружает бэкенд), либо по нажатию на кнопку "Enter"/или в пустую область (событие @change), что в моём случае тоже не совсем правильно.

Вопрос:

1. Как изменить метод "sendSearch()" таким образом, что бы он выполнялся к примеру не чаще 1 раза в секунду при вводе текста?
2. Или что лучше всего по окончанию ввода поиска (но тут абстракция т.к. мы не знаем закончил пользователь ввод или нет, а клик мимо поиска не всегда значит окончание поиска)

Comment: почитай про throttle и  debounce

Comment: Спасибо, по вашей подсказке понял, что надо использовать тротл, но не стал писать функцию с нуля, а просто подключил из npm `lodash.throttle`

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, сам же и отвечу.
Для конкретного случая, что бы выполнить задержку к примеру в 1 секунда, сделал следующее:

1. Установил npm пакет: `npm i lodash.throttle` (либо можно установить пакет lodash целиком `npm i lodash`)
2. Подключаем `import throttle from 'lodash.throttle'`
3. Создаём вычисляемое свойство computed:

   ```
    throttledSend() { return throttle(this.sendSearch, 1000) }
   ```
4. input заменяем на следующий (к примеру): `<input type="text" v-model.trim="query" @input="throttledSend">`